# Unable to cancel a query in DB2

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

I have the following stored procedure in DB2:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CANCEL_ACTIVITY (IN application_handle INTEGER)
  LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
  DECLARE UOW_ID INTEGER;
  DECLARE ACTIVITY_ID  INTEGER;

  FOR v AS cur1 CURSOR FOR
    SELECT UOW_ID, ACTIVITY_ID FROM TABLE(SYSPROC.MON_GET_ACTIVITY(application_handle, -1))
  DO
    CALL WLM_CANCEL_ACTIVITY(application_handle, v.uow_id, v.activity_id);
  END FOR ;
END
```

Using the following query, I am able to find my connection ID:

```
SELECT MON_GET_APPLICATION_HANDLE() from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

Which would return a value like `36547`. So I call the procedure I just created like so:

```
CALL CANCEL_ACTIVITY(36547);
```

As a result, I get the following:

[image]

However, if I execute the query that gets connection IDs again, it doesn't seem like that connection ID is gone. I still get the `36547` value returned.

I am quite confused whether this query canceling is working at all. I am getting a range of different type of errors in different environments I am executing the code at.

When I am running it as a SQL query, I get the above error code / response. When my code is being executed in my webpage, I get the following error:

```
Cannot cancel queries: Java::ComIbmDb2JccAm::SqlDataException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-802, SQLSTATE=22003, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.16.53
```

I am curious what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to read [Canceling Activies](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.wlm.doc/doc/t0052787.html) in the DB2 documentation. Canceling an activity is not closing a connection, but selectively aborting a query or other running tasks:

> If an activity is consuming too many resources, or is running too
>   long, you can cancel it. Canceling an activity is gentler than forcing
>   the application that submitted the activity. A canceled activity
>   returns SQL4725N to the user, but does not end the connection or
>   affect any other user activity. Forcing the application ends both the
>   connection and user activities.

In your procedure you are looking for the app handle, uow and a specific activity ID. Have you looked what the activity you are going to cancel is/was doing? You could use `WLM_CAPTURE_ACTIVITY_IN_PROGRESS` to first dump information about that activity, so that you can debug your scenario.

Comment: Hi @data_henrik -- thanks for the explanation. Is this the full query to cancel an activity? `CALL WLM_CANCEL_ACTIVITY (1, 2, 5)`

Comment: Yes, app handle/UOW identifier/activity id.

Comment: wait, if you check out my procedure, that's what I am doing, no? I use `CALL WLM_CANCEL_ACTIVITY(..)`

Comment: You are passing in an app handle, but a specific activity is canceled. What exactly do you expect to cancel...?